# How do I get rid of my Ubuntu One account?

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

Is it possible? The problem is that my brother created an "Ubuntu One" account and we didn't know that we could create an account using more than 1 e-mail, so now we want create a account with his e-mail and mine, but I can't because his e-mail is registered...

So how can we eliminate that account?

Comment: Are you asking about how to delete the U1 account, or to just reset the client side so you can log in with a different U1 account?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can add more email addresses, you should still have your own accounts. Sharing files and folders between accounts is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting Canonical?  Send them a quick note and see if they can adjust the addressing for you.  https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/